# How To Keep Django Logic To The Back-End

Tags: django, django-templates, django-database

I have a number of connected `model`s:

```
class User(models.Model):
    individual_units = models.ManyToManyField(BaseUnit)
    unit_packages = models.ManyToManyField(UnitPackage)

class BaseUnit(models.Model):

class UnitPackage(models.Model):
    individual_units = models.ManyToManyField(BaseUnit)

class UnitFiles(models.Model):
    base_unit = models.ForeignKey(BaseUnit)
    lesson_number = models.CharField()

class UserUnitData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(BaseUnit)
    package = models.ForeignKey(UnitPackage)

class UserLessonData(models.Model):
    user_unit_data = models.ForeignKey(UserUnitData)
    lesson_number = models.CharField()

class UserUploadedFile(models.Model):
    user_lesson_data = models.ForeignKey(UserLessonData)
```

I need to print data from a single user on a page. Data from different `model`s is spread over the page, not grouped together. For example:

```
Loop over each UnitPackage

Within each UnitPackage print each BaseUnit

Within each BaseUnit print each related UnitFiles

Then print each UserUploadedFile

After this has been done loop through every second BaseUnit

Print each BaseUnits UserLessonData

etc..
```

Sure I can gather all those `model`s in my view, but as data from each is printed throughout the document, I can't see how it's possible to perform the logic within my `view`. I have massive, nested loops within my template:

```
{% for unit_data in user.unit_data.all %}
{% if unit_data.unit_id == unit.id and unit_data.package_id == package.id %}
{% for extra_data in unit_data.user_lesson_data.all %}
{% if extra_data.lesson_number|add:0 == iteration|add:1 %}
{% if extra_data.completed == True %}
<td><input type='checkbox' disabled="disabled" name='completed' checked></td>
{% else %}
<td><input type='checkbox' disabled="disabled" name='completed'></td>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

At times I'm repeating very similar loops to retrieve data at different areas in the page.

Is there any way I can remove this logic from my templates? Does this suggest terrible DB design?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're representing here is the hierarchy of your object model - to that extent there is no escaping it if that is a good representation of the real world you're modelling.

From a personal perspective I would suggest that you extract the logic to your views - so that they do the filtering and your web page iterates through that list.

For example,

```
{% for unit_data in user.unit_data.all %}
{% if unit_data.unit_id == unit.id and unit_data.package_id == package.id %}
```

Might become in views.py

```
unitdatalist = unit_data.objects.filter(unit_id = unit.id, package_id = package.id)
```

And then in your template you just have the following (assuming that you have passed via the context)

```
{% for unitdata in unitdatalist %}
```

That way, you have separated out some of the logic from the presentation.

Comment: Thank you. What your suggesting does make sense, though I need to run that code maybe 20 times in my template, once for each ```unit```. If I ran ```unitdatalist = unit_data.objects.filter(unit_id = unit.id, package_id = package.id)``` that would only collect the ```unit_data``` for a single unit wouldn't it?

Comment: It would yes, as your if statement was filtering out all unit_data objects that didn't match the unit or package id then I'd assumed that was what you'd wanted. If you need to iterate through units or packages, you could apply the similar logic - again, moving it to your view so that the template is simpler